# How to get email notification when labels assigned to issue change

Tags: github

I correctly receive (email) notifications every time a new comment is posted to an issue.

Is there a way to get notifications every time labels assigned to an issue are changed too?
E.g. if a user assigns a new label, if a user deletes an existing label, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: You could create a DIY webhook to do it.

Comment: Are you talking about https://developer.github.com/webhooks/? Cool!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm sorry but no, there isn't.

As you can see in the [GitHub Notification Docs](https://help.github.com/articles/about-notifications/):

> **About notifications**
>
> See updates on the important activities you're
> interested in.
>
> Notifications can be viewed on GitHub or in an email.
>
> **Types of notifications**
>
> GitHub delivers two kinds of notifications:
>
> -Participating notifications are those in which you are directly
> involved in a conversation. You will automatically receive these
> notifications when:
>
> - Someone mentions you or a team you're a member of
> - You are assigned to an issue or pull request
> - Someone makes a comment in a conversation you're subscribed to
>
> -Watching notifications are those in which you are actively watching a repository, but aren't necessarily participating.
> You will automatically receive these notifications for:
>
> - Opened issues and their comments
> - Opened pull requests and their comments
> - Comments on any commits Published releases

There is no option to get notifications every time labels assigned to an issue are changed, but you can request this feature to GitHub at [How To: Submit a bug, issue, or feature request](https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/wiki/How-To:-Submit-a-bug,-issue,-or-feature-request)